# Fourier Series of $f=x$ in $[0,2\pi)$

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have to find the Fourier Series of $f=x$ in $[0,2\pi)$, I already know that $g=x$ in $[-\pi,\pi)$ is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (-2) }{n} \sin(nx) $$
How does the difference in the region change me, since in both regions the period is $2\pi$?

Comment: Let $y=x+\pi\ or\ x=y-\pi$.  Then $sin(nx)=sin(ny-n\pi)=sin(ny)cos(n\pi)-cos(ny)sin(n\pi)=(-1)^nsin(ny)$.  Use this.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that
$$
          x= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(-2)}{n}\sin(nx),\;\;\; -\pi < x < \pi,
$$
then
$$
                 x-\pi=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(-2)}{n}\sin(n(x-\pi)), \;\;\; 0 < x < 2\pi.
$$

Using
\begin{align}
     \sin(n(x-\pi))& =\sin(nx)\cos(-n\pi)+\cos(nx)\sin(-n\pi)\\
   &=(-1)^n\sin(nx)
\end{align}
gives
$$
       x = \pi-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n}\sin(nx),\;\;\; 0 < x < 2\pi.
$$